# callback.customMessage is not a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-cognito

I am working on implementing custom authentication. This is the code -

```
cognitoUser.initiateAuth(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: async (result) => {
            console.log('initiateAuth result -', result);
            authenticateUser.initiateAuth(params, (err, data) => {
                if(err) {
                    console.log('initiateAuth err 1 -', err);
                } else {
                    console.log('initiateAuth result 1 -', data)
                }
            })
        },
        onFailure: async (err) => {
            console.log('initiateAuth err -', err)
        },
        customChallenge: async (challengeParameters) => {
            // User authentication depends on challenge response
            var challengeResponses = 'challenge-answer';
            cognitoUser.sendCustomChallengeAnswer(challengeResponses, {
                onSuccess: async (result) => {
                    console.log('challenge result -', result)
                },
                onFailure: async (err) => {
                    console.log('challenge err -', err)
                }
            });
        },
    })
```

But I am still getting callback error.
Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: `.customMessage` does not appear in your code. What line is throwing this exception? What is the full text and stack trace of that exception?

Comment: sorry, it's .customChallenge, not .customMessage